# assignment operator in c++ delete memory

Tags: c++

I'm trying to delete the memory first before allocate new memory, but i dont know how to make, and I have one problem when try to resize the matrix.

```
Matrix & operator=(const Matrix &B){            
            row = B.row;
            col = B.col;

            if (matrix==0){
                matrix = new int*[row];
                for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
                    matrix[i] = new int[col];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {                 
                    matrix[i][j] = B.matrix[i][j];
                }
            }   
        return *this;

    }
```

For example (resize)

```
Matrix matrixA(1, 1);
Matrix matrixB(2, 2);
matrixA = matrixB;
```

Thank you & best regards

Comment: What is the problem?  Wouldn't a plain old `delete[]` be the obvious way to go?  Note however, that you should probably use a `std::vector` instead, and all your memory management troubles will simply go away.

Comment: Also be aware of the `&B == this` case (self-assignment).

Comment: yes i know the class vector, but in this exercise is no allow use vector. And dont know the way to solve this @ 5gon12eder

Comment: You might also want to check out the [copy and swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `delete[]` on each row then on matrix.

```
if (matrix!=NULL){
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
        delete[] matrix[i];
    delete[] matrix;
}
row = B.row;
col = B.col;
matrix = new int*[row];
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    matrix[i] = new int[col];
```

Note that this does not copy the contents of the source matrix. Need another loop for that

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
        matrix[i][j] = B.matrix[i][j];
```

Comment: @user243380 Look back in another minute or two. I forgot a vital part and am editing the answer.

Comment: @user243380  Updated to move reassignment of row and col to after using them to delete the old matrix. Oops. added quickie loop t copy data from Matrix B to this.